# Angular build getting failed when running through jenkins pipeline

Tags: angular, npm, sass, angular-builder

I am trying to build my angular app through jenkins pipeline. However the build fails with this error. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this error. I tried installing sass package. but that didnt help.  Can anyone help on this ?

```
- Generating browser application bundles...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: ./src/styles/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
    ╷
114 │       @each $key, $value in $gutters {
    │                             ^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 114:29       @content
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss 32:3                @import
  src/styles/vendors/_bootstrap.scss 7:9                     @import
  src/styles/vendors/_vendors.scss 4:9                       @import
  src/styles/main.scss 7:9                                   root stylesheet
```

Comment: This seems to be problem related to `node-sass`, you may have to check `node version` and `node-sass` version compatibility